# php INSERT statement not working, no echo or error received

Tags: php

In PHP, I am attempting to insert sign up information into a database.  I have worked through a bunch of errors and now I am not getting anything in my window after submitting the form and nothing writes to the database.  The window comes up blank.  I have researched answers but have found nothing to assist.  I have re-written my VALUES statement several times using various techniques, both trying to use certain code characters and not using them.  Characters include {}, [] and "" as well as ''.

I have not yet written statements to clean my data, I do realize this will be necessary, I just want to get the script functioning first.

The current code for my form resides in one file and my current PHP code resides in a different file which is referenced by the first file.  Here is my current PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$band_name = $_POST['band_name'];
$label_name = $_POST['label_name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$confirm_email == ['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password == ['$password'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'fishstench', 'Site Database.mwb.bak')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "INSERT INTO Users (User_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, (SHA)Password, Email, Join_Date " . 
"VALUES ('{$_POST[First_Name]}','{$_POST[Last_Name]}','{$_POST[User_Name]}','{$_POST[Password]},','{$_POST[Email]}','{$_POST[date]}')";

$query = "INSERT INTO Location (City, State, Zip_Code " .
"VALUES '{$_POST[City]}','{$_POST[State]}','{$_POST[Zip_Code]}')";

$query = "INSERT INTO Band_Name (Band_Name, Label_Name " .
"VALUES '{$_POST[Band_Name]}','{$_POST[Zip_Code]}')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);

echo 'Thanks for signing up!<br />';

} ?>
```

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file .. Does it return anything?

Comment: This is probably the most SQL Injection vulnerable code I've seen today. Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: @vascowhite: Indeed he is! But it's still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I'm sure you have this covered, but are you sure your capitalization matches the exact table and field names?

Answer (score 1):

First, only the last query is gets executed, as you are overwriting the above 2 (I think that's not what you want?).

Check your `$_POST` array if the `submit(key)` is set, to pass the check, by using a `var_dump` or `print_r` just before the check.

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   ....
   }
```

These lines need to have assignment operator `=`, instead of comparison operator `==`,

```
 $confirm_email == ['email'];
 $confirm_password == ['$password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing parenthesis in your first query. I think it should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (User_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, (SHA)Password, Email, Join_Date) " . 
"VALUES ('{$_POST[First_Name]}','{$_POST[Last_Name]}','{$_POST[User_Name]}','{$_POST[Password]},','{$_POST[Email]}','{$_POST[date]}')";
```

Also, the parentheses in your other queries seem to be incorrect I think they should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Location (City, State, Zip_Code) " .
"VALUES ('{$_POST[City]}','{$_POST[State]}','{$_POST[Zip_Code]}')";

$query = "INSERT INTO Band_Name (Band_Name, Label_Name) " .
"VALUES ('{$_POST[Band_Name]}','{$_POST[Zip_Code]}')";
```

In the future, to detect errors, check the result to see if there is an error:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $connection);
if (!$result) {
    exit("mysqli_query() error: ", mysqli_error($connection), "\nquery was: $query\n");
}
```

Comment: Also, as @coder1984 mentioned, only the last query will get executed.

Comment: `$confirm_email`, `$confirm_password` are broken and not being pulled from $_POST vars either.